# CodeIgniter: how to change controller name dynamically

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to change the function name of a controller according to a company name.

Below is the function called company. Now, If the company XXX is logged in I need to change the function name with XXX.

**Example:**
http://example.com/projects/app/XXX

```
 $company = getCompanyName();
 public function $company {

     //code...

    }
```

How can I set the function name dynamically?

Comment: why not to use method argument?

Comment: routes in codeigniter https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: Why you need to create the function name dynamically, instead you can show the company name in the url and pull the corresponding data from the database or elsewhere using a generalised function. May be you can use  (:any ) in that part of the url where the company name appears and direct it to the generalised function for fetching informations about the company based on the company name or ID .

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this pattern before.

And I don't think it is possible in PHP to name functions using variables as you mentionned in your code.

What I think the appropriate way to go is to use a method argument. An example code would be:

```
public function controllerAction(Request $request)
     $company = getCompanyName($request);
     $this->method($company);
     //code...

    }
 public function method($company)

     //code...

    }
```

As you can see, this approach requires you to retrieve the info from the Request object.